# what is the -J-XX meaning? appear in the java command line

Tags: java, performance, command-line-arguments

I found in the java command line, there is the parameter like " -J-XX:ThreadStackSize=256  -J-verbosegc", i know the -XX but how about the -J ? anyone knows? Thanks

Comment: Does your JVM run when you use them? What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Some things running on a JVM accept such parameters to be passed directly through to the JVM startup. An example is jruby. The `-J` is stripped off before passing through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must get passed through to some other environment, maybe you have a script doing something because here I get

```
efrisch@eeyore ~ $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
efrisch@eeyore ~ $ java -J-XX:ThreadStackSize=256 -J-verbosegc
Unrecognized option: -J-XX:ThreadStackSize=256
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

In other words, something is taking the "-J" options off at some point (that is both "-J-XX:ThreadStackSize=256" and "-J-verbosegc") either completely or just the leading "-J".

Comment: Same for Java `1.7.0_45`. `Unrecognized option`. I quite agree with you on the conclusion as well, though I think you should point out the parameter taken are `-J-XX:ThreadStackSize` and `-J-verbosegc` and not just `-J` since this is what can be concluded from the error message

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you r correct, it was found in the script of the Resin startup. i have found the logic for "-J". Thanks!